# Any plugin using jquery that can do some layout like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

[image]

Without javascript, I think about just float left all the element but I do need to control the size of the picture to be 2 times or 4 times height or width to each other

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you are trying to do? You need to use CSS to position elements like that (which I think is what you are looking for).

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) is the closest thing I'm aware of.